# My "keybore" is key-boring me! Help me find a minimal keystrokes

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

Credits to [@Agawa001](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38337/agawa001) for coming up with this question.

## Explanation

My new "keybore" only has 2 buttons, namely `+` and `-`.

The number in the memory starts at `0`.

Each consecutive press of `+` or `-` will increment/decrement the memory for exactly how many times it has been pressed consecutively.

Therefore, if you press `+` 4 times, first time it adds 1, the second time it adds 2, the third time it adds 3, the fourth time it adds 4, giving you `10` (ten).

Now, if you press `-` 3 times, the first time it subtracts 1, the second time 2, the third time 3, leaving you with `4` (four).

## TL;DR

Given a string of + and -, divide it at each change of character. Then each resulting string of m `+` symbols adds the m-th triangle number, and each string of n `-` symbols subtracts the n-th triangle number.

## Walk-through

Now, if you still do not understand, I will show you how `+++--+--` creates `1`.

```
Program   | Counter | Memory
----------------------------
          |  0      | 0
+         | +1      | 1
++        | +2      | 3
+++       | +3      | 6
+++-      | -1      | 5
+++--     | -2      | 3
+++--+    | +1      | 4
+++--+-   | -1      | 3
+++--+--  | -2      | 1
```

## Task

- You will take a positive integer as input, either as functional argument or from STDIN.
- Then, you will output/print the minimum number of keystrokes needed to create that number using the method above.

## Testcases

Since rearranging the `+` or `-` runs gives the same number, for each such group only the lexicographically earliest sequence is listed.

```
Input | Output | Possible corresponding sequences
-------------------------------------------------
    4 |      5 | -+++-
    6 |      3 | +++
    9 |      5 | ++++-
   11 |      7 | +++-+++
   12 |      7 | +++++--, ++++-++
   19 |      8 | -++++++-
   39 |     12 | +++++++++---
   40 |     13 | +++++++++---+, ++++++++-+++-
   45 |      9 | +++++++++
   97 |     20 | ++++++++++++++--+---, +++++++++++++-++++--, ++++++++++++-++++++-
  361 |     34 | ++++++++++++++++++++++++++-+++-+++
```

## Extra resources

- [Proof that any number can be made](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29964994#29964994): basically, by repeating `++-`, you can obtain any even number. To obtain the odd numbers, just put a `+` at the end.
- Another general way to obtain any number. For example, to generate `50`, a way is to press `+` 50 times, and then press `-` 49 times.
- [Solution of the first 50 numbers](http://pastebin.com/Cfq7A8Eg).
- [Obligatory JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryr5tqt5/8/).

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes wins.

Comment: Does that mean... you are keybored?

Comment: I think you're OK with 10 test cases now (including mine).

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος The 12 test case has been added, with a slight modification (since `+++++--` is also an alternative, but I removed `++-++++` since that's equivalent to `++++-++`). I've still got one more case I'd like to add later in case anyone comes up with an efficient solution, if I manage generate it.

Comment: @Sp3000 I did not want `++-++++` removed. Also, this was MY edit, not YOURS.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Only 1 solution from each set of equivalent solutions is listed - I thought that if all the minimal solutions were listed, the test cases would be unnecessarily long (there's 6 solutions for 40 and 17 solutions for 97). I do apologise if that intention was not clear. Also you were missing `+++++--` (or, equivalently, `--+++++`), which is why I felt the need to edit in the first place.

Comment: @Sp3000 Then, why 97 has 3 solutions visible?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος The other 14 solutions are just one of those three solutions with the `+` or `-` groups rearranged.

Comment: Correction: There's actually 20, not 17 (miscounted), but they're still all rearrangements of those three types.

Comment: I am surprised this resisted a straightforward solution until now...

Comment: @Sp3000 I mean, 3 are visible on 97, while the others have 1 or 2.

Comment: `s=>s.replace(/([-+])\1*/g,t=>r+=(l=t.length)*++l/2*(t<'-'||-1),r=0)&&r`, so if anyone posts that as a challenge, I have a 70 byte solution in JavaScript (ES6).

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Do you get that, if you rearrange the `+`/`-` runs as long as they still alternate between `+` and `-`, you always get another valid solution? e.g. `++++++++-+++-`, `-++++++++-+++`, `+++-++++++++-` and `-+++-++++++++` are all equivalent solutions for 40 because they all correspond to `36+6-1-1`, but `+++++++++---+` is different (`45+1-6`). 97 has 3 solutions listed because that's how many groups of equivalent solutions there are (and also why that test case is there), while others have 1 or 2 because that's how many groups of equivalent solutions *they* have.

Comment: I would like to post a non-inefficient solution, but it will be large in size. How about a bonus to reduce the size? :D

Comment: better simpler proof that any number can be made: `"+"*n+"-"*(n-1)` yields n

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>43</s> 29 bytes

```
E:"@TFEqZ^!"@Y'tQ**s]vGE=a?@.
```

This is memory- and time-inefficient. The online compiler can handle up to input `45` only.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=RToiQFRGRXFaXiEiQFkndFEqKnNddkdFPWE_QC4&input=MTk)

Here's a [modified version](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkBFWEo6IkBURkVxWl4hIkBZJ3RRKipzXXZKPWE_QEQu&input=WzQgNiA5IDExIDEyIDE5IDM5IDQwXQ) with all test cases up to `40` (it takes almost a minute in the online compiler).

#### Explanation

This tests all possible key-press sequences of each length, in order of increasing length, until a valid sequence is found.

```
E:       % Range [1 2 ... 2*N] where N is implicit input. The required sequence length is
         % less than 2*N, so this is enough
"        % For each
  @      %   Push current value: length of sequence
  TFEq   %   Push array [1 -1]
  Z^     %   Cartesian power. Gives all possible sequences of 1, -1 of that length
  !      %   Transpose. Each sequence is now a row
  "      %   For each sequence
    @    %     Push current sequence
    Y'   %     Run-length decoding: Pushes an array of values 1 and -1, and then an
         %     array of run-lengths
    tQ*  %     Duplicate, add 1, multiply. Gives twice the triangular number for each run
    *    %     Multiply element-wise by 1 or -1 to produce correct sign
    s    %     Sum of array. This is the number produced by the current sequence
  ]      %   End for
  v      %   Concatenate all numbers into an array
  GE=a   %   True if any of those numbers equals twice the input
  ?      %   If so
    @    %     Push current sequence length. This is the final result
    .    %     Break loop
         %   End if
         % End for
         % Implicit display
```

Comment: @Sp3000 I've added one too, so, for reference, 4, 6, 9 and 19 are the test cases referred to, in order.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 119 bytes

```
def g(n,i=0,s=''):
 c=x=t=0
 for d in s:C=int(d)*2-1;t=(c==C)*t+1;c=C;x+=c*t
 return(x==n)*len(s)or g(n,i+1,bin(i)[3:])
```

Very slow brute-force approach. The third line computes the score of a string `x`; the other lines loop over all possible binary strings until one whose score equals the argument is found.

@Leaky saved three bytes!

Comment: `s/x==n and len/(x==n)*len/`

Comment: It might save some bytes to get rid of `s` and just use repeated division, like this: `def f(n): \n while n>0:print n%2;n/=2`

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 25 bytes

```
ffqyQ.as-Mc*RhdY2{s.pM./T
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ffqyQ.as-Mc*RhdY2%7Bs.pM.%2FT&input=19&debug=0)

This is extremely inefficient, and runs out of memory for `f(n)` ≥ 11. It calculates `f(22)` = 10 in about 10 seconds on my laptop.

#### Explanation

- Starting from 1, loop through numbers `T`. (`f`)

  - Generate all partitions of `T`. (`./T`)
  - Generate all permutations of those. (`.pM`)
  - Flatten the list. (`s`)
  - Uniquify the list. (`{`) This step *could* be removed, but it makes the  code much faster.
  - Filter the resulting permutations of partitions: (`f`)

    - Multiply each number `d` of the partition (`*R`) by itself plus one (`hd`). This gives double the number to add/subtract to the result.
    - Chop the list to parts of length 2. (`c`…`2`)
    - Subtract any second number in those parts from the second number. (`-M`)
    - Sum the results. This gives double the resulting number if the partition permutation was interpreted as number of additions, then subtractions, etc.
    - Take the absolute value. (`.a`) If the result was negative, swapping the additions and subtractions gets the positive result.
    - Check if the result equals double the input. (`qyQ`) In this case the partition permutation is correct, return it.
  - If the filter returned any results, there was a solution of length `T`. Return and print `T`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>105</s> 100 bytes

Uses an inefficient breadth-first search.

```
def k(n):
 m=t=l=0;h=[]
 while m-n:o=1-2*(t>0);(m,t,l),*h=h+[(m+t-o,t-o,l+1),(m+o,o,l+1)]
 return l
```

- `h` is a list used as a queue
- `m` is the value of the sequence at the head of the list
- `t` is the last number added to `m`
- `l` is the length of the sequence that generated `m`
- `o` is +/-1, the sign is opposite the sign of `t`

Edit: Leaky Nun shaved five bytes.

Comment: `s/m,t,l,h=0,0,0,[]/m=t=l=0,h=[]/`

Comment: `s/while m!=n/while m-n/`